# How to put a runnable thread in a java class

Tags: java, multithreading, url

first off, I have never used threads before, so please forgive any lax terminology. I have three similar, but different classes, all which require information to be read from the internet, so I wanted to make a thread that runs in the background while the program uses a local copy of what it got online. However, each class needs their own special input and therefore I can't make one main runnable class.

The question: Should I make three separate Threads, one for each program, or can I embed a Runnable Thread in each class? How do I do it?

Thanks for the help

ps. If you want to see my program (at least a version of it) go to jacobfakult.50webs.com/quizzes/program... sorry for the advertisement, thanks again!

Comment: I think it would be better to show your src code rather than the program.

Comment: Sounds to me that you should read some documentation.  SO is not your research assistant.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you a straight answer since you *have never used threads before*, so I would recommend first reading about this topic. This is the official resource: [Lesson: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

After reading all this, you will now understand that you want to use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that will handle the threads for you. The only thing that matters now is the current application design that will do the work on each thread, in this case, download content from internet.

*Easy* way: make your three (or more) classes to implement the `Runnable` interface and do all the work in the `run` method. Example:

```
public class Foo implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doWork();
    }
    public void doWork() {
        //download files or whatever you want/need to do
    }
}

public class BigWorker {
    private static final int NUM_OF_THREADS = 3;
    public void doWork() {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS);
        es.execute(new Foo());
        //assuming Bar and Baz are the other two classes...
        es.execute(new Bar());
        es.execute(new Baz());
        //it is A MUST to call this method
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `public class Foo implements Runnable`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the subject, but here are my two cents(for free):

1. Have a background thread that handles requests from all three of your classes that need to download information.
2. Have a List of requests so that the background thread can process the requests synchronously.
3. When a class need to download information, just add to that list of requests

After some googling it seems there is no limit to the amount of threads you can have, but the higher the number of threads, the lower the benefit each thread provides. In my opinion one thread would suffice for your task.

example:

```
//maybe make an Request class that specifies the url of what you want to download,
//and what to do with response
//put this ArrayList as a member field in the class you are making the thread
ArrayList<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();

Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        while(true)
            {
                if(requests.size() > 0)
                {
                    Request oldestRequest = requests.get(0);

                    //process the request

                    test.remove(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    //checks every 10 seconds if there is a request
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                }
            }
        }
    };
backgroundThread.start();
```

Comment: There's no need to reinvent this wheel. The `ExecutorService` already handles this for you, depending on the implementation used. Check the links in my answer to find more about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*
     * i dont understand totally what your point is, but assume
     * we have 3 classes that needs to use one Runnable task ...
     * Threads are Runnable ... any way, so
     */

    // create your runnable task
    class ReadDataOnline implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // read data from the internet and update something or what ever
        }
    }


    // create your classes that will use this task
    class ClassOne{
        private ReadDataOnline runnable = null;
        private Thread reader = null;

        ClassOne(ReadDataOnline runnable){
            this.runnable = runnable;
            reader = new Thread(runnable);
        }

        void useTask(){
            // start your new Thread in the background, which will use
            // the Runnable task in the parameter
            reader.start();
        }
    }

    class ClassTwo {
        private ReadDataOnline runnable = null;
        private Thread reader = null;

        ClassTwo(ReadDataOnline runnable) {
            this.runnable = runnable;
            reader = new Thread(runnable);
        }

        void useTask() {
            // start your new Thread in the background, which will use
            // the Runnable task in the parameter
            reader.start();
        }
    }

    class ClassThree {
        private ReadDataOnline runnable = null;
        private Thread reader = null;

        ClassThree(ReadDataOnline runnable) {
            this.runnable = runnable;
            reader = new Thread(runnable);
        }

        void useTask() {
            // start your new Thread in the background, which will use
            // the Runnable task in the parameter
            reader.start();
        }
    }


    class MainClass{

        public void doStuff(){

            ReadDataOnline runnable = new ReadDataOnline();

            // use the same runnable task in the three classes
            ClassOne classOne = new ClassOne(runnable);
            ClassTwo classTwo = new ClassTwo(runnable);
            ClassThree classThree = new ClassThree(runnable);

            // let classOne start using the Task
            classOne.useTask();

            // now the Task status is updated/modified by classOne,
            // let classTwo use the task in it's new state
            classTwo.useTask();

            // and so on
            classThree.useTask();

            /*
             * since we are not talking about a specefic case, i cant tell
             * what is the task or what to do with it, but put in mind that
             * synchronizing your methods is very important since multi-threading
             * doesnt guarantee the order of the threads, and also they wont
             * be synchronized with each other unless your methods are synchronized 
             * (or you use synchronization blocks)
             */

            // i know this example isnt very good, but at least it shows how to use
            // the same task in multiple Threads or classes that are backed with
            // different threads



        }


    }
```